# Activity android:label change application name

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

I started a new project without an activity, I then created my own and register them to manifest as below. But it seams whenever I placed a label on my LoginActivity it changes the application name.

```
<application
    android:name=".app.ApplicationController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_screen_label"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

</application>
```

And my string resources

```
<string name="app_name">My ToDo</string>
<string name="login_screen_label">Log in</string>
```

What am i doing wrong

UPDATE `actitity_login.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can  you post your Activity xml code

Comment: Updated @Abhishekkumar

Comment: Go with my Answer, sure it will work for you @Emmanuel

Comment: No need to set `Activity` title programatically just set `label` in both `application` and `Activity` tag

Comment: I don't get your question What do you mean by `it changes the application name`? do you mean the name on launcher icon or name on ActionBar ?

Comment: Name of the launcher icon @ADM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:label="app name"` in `application` tag

Using `android:label` in `application` tag will set Application name. And using `android:label` in `Activity` tag will set the title of the `Activity`.

Comment: I go with @AbuYousuf answer, that makes the most sense

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from mainfests

```
android:label="@string/login_screen_label"
```

Comment: Its also a fix! But it doesn't have to  behave that way . . .

Comment: `because label set only application tag` this is not true . Both labels have different purpose .

Comment: @ADM ok you are right we can also used label in activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);   
toolbar.setTitle(your label);
```

if you are using AppTheme with Actionbar like DarkActionbar so you need to setup your toolbar and set title in toolbar as above

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below code inside your `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

FULL CODE :

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right.
According to android developer API documents, 'label' in 'activity' is first priority then in 'application'.

To change in-app label use

```
title=""
```

In

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
}
```